# "All Supported" in "Files of type:" combobox of QFileDialog

Tags: xml, qt, format, mime, qfiledialog

I made a subclass of QFileDialog and put some file formats in "Files of type" combobox. Expet from these file formats, I want to have an  "All Supported" item in this combobox. When some selects "All Supported", they will be able to select only the files of the supported formats.

I have already looked at the cocept of QMimeDatabase but I am quite confused on how and where  can make the XML file, containing my custom formats. According to the documentation:

"Applications which want to define custom MIME types need to install an XML file into the locations searched for MIME definitions. These locations can be queried with

```
QStandardPaths::locateAll(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation, QLatin1String("mime/packages"),
                          QStandardPaths::LocateDirectory);
```

"

When I am calling locateAll, I get an empty QStringList.

So my questions are:

1. Do I really need the concept of some new entries in QMimeDatabase?
2. If yes, where is the directory that I have to put my XML file?

Comment: Everything is written here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qmimedatabase.html#details . Guess, you're not using linux...

Comment: The documentation does not help me enough, as long as I have a specific question on it. (Yes I am not currently using Linux, but my application should also run on Linux).

Comment: MIME types work different in different OS. I don't have Qt5 sources right now, but I'm sure in Windows `QMimeDatabase` either pre-hardcoded or uses registry. As for your own types, you could add them to the result list manually in code.

Comment: Why do you need mime definition in the first place? `QFileDialog` requires only format name and file masks, doesn't it?